# Linking to google map directions with full address as destination parameter drops destination

Tags: google-maps, google-directions-api

I am generating a URL that should link a user from an email to google directions to a destination from their current location. I am following the google documentation found here https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action but I am running into problems that vary by client.

We noticed that on Android phones, the destination is not filled in. When I add `?saddr=Current+Location`, the destination is filled in, but in other languages besides english, it doesn't always work (even with the correct translation). Is there something wrong with the way I am formatting that destination? Is there a correct cross-client way of generating a link to a destination from a user's current location?
Thanks!

I have read through all the existing Stack Overflow discussions on this and tried a solution by passing `saddr=Current+location` mentioned in this article http://gearside.com/easily-link-to-locations-and-directions-using-the-new-google-maps/. I think this only works on US phones, even when "current location" is translated correctly.

```py
       params = {}
       destination = [
                self.street,
                self.city,
                self.province,
                self.postal_code,
                self.country,
       ]

        destination = ','.join(d for d in destination if d)
        params['destination'] = destination
        params = {k:v.encode('utf-8') for (k,v) in params.iteritems()}

        url = "https://maps.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&%s" % urlencode(params)
        return url
```

That creates the url `https://maps.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&destination=24+Ocean+St%2CSanta+Cruz%2CCA%2C95060%2CUS`.

I expect the url to open either the maps app or a google maps webpage with directions to a destination from the user's current location. Instead I get a map with the current location focused, and no destination filled in.

UPDATE: I was using the wrong subdomain (maps.google.com instead of www.google.com). Using www actually fixed the issue.

Comment: Where in the **official** documentation did you read about that `Current+location` value?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I should have mentioned that I did not see that anywhere in the docs. I found that solution on stack overflow. I'm looking for a solution without that.

Comment: I was using the wrong subdomain